# how to extends multiple classes in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, flutter, multiple-inheritance

I am developing an application in a flutter, and I want to extend one library class in `AppDelegate.swift` file. As iOS is not supporting multiple inheritances I can't extend the library class and `FlutterAppDelegate` class together.

Can someone help me with this? Is there any other way to achieve this kind of function?

Here is some code snippet for ios

App's `AppDelegate.swift`

```
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
      override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
      GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)      
      return true
  }
}
```

This is my library's header class which I also want to extends to `AppDelegate`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegateSEG : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property(strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

This is my AppDelegateSEG.m

```
//  AppDelegateSEG.m
//  ObjcPodsSample
//
//

#import "AppDelegateSEG.h"
#import "SEGAppsFlyerIntegrationFactory.h"
#import <AppTrackingTransparency/AppTrackingTransparency.h>


@interface AppDelegateSEG ()

@end

@interface AppDelegateSEG ()<SEGAppsFlyerLibDelegate>

@end

@implementation AppDelegateSEG


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    
    // For ApsFlyer debug logs
    [AppsFlyerLib shared].isDebug = YES;
    
//    [[AppsFlyerLib shared] waitForATTUserAutxhorizationWithTimeoutInterval:60];
    /*
     Based on your needs you can either pass a delegate to process deferred
     and direct deeplinking callbacks or disregard them.
     If you choose to use the delegate, see extension to this class below
     */
//    SEGAppsFlyerIntegrationFactory* factoryNoDelegate = [SEGAppsFlyerIntegrationFactory instance];
    SEGAppsFlyerIntegrationFactory* factoryWithDelegate = [SEGAppsFlyerIntegrationFactory createWithLaunchDelegate:self];
    
    SEGAnalyticsConfiguration *config = [SEGAnalyticsConfiguration configurationWithWriteKey:@"********"];
//    [config use:factoryNoDelegate];
    [config use:factoryWithDelegate];  // use this if you want to get conversion data in the app. Read more in the integration guide
    config.enableAdvertisingTracking = YES;       //OPTIONAL
    config.trackApplicationLifecycleEvents = YES; //OPTIONAL
    config.trackDeepLinks = YES;                  //OPTIONAL
    config.trackPushNotifications = YES;          //OPTIONAL
    [SEGAnalytics debug:YES];                     //OPTIONAL
    [SEGAnalytics setupWithConfiguration:config];
  
    NSLog(@"before delay");
    NSString *userId =  [[SEGAnalytics sharedAnalytics] getAnonymousId];
    NSLog(@"----%@", userId);
    [[SEGAnalytics sharedAnalytics] identify:(userId)];
//    [[SEGAnalytics sharedAnalytics] identify:userId];

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
//     Code below is to collect IDFA. Read more here - https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011451918-iOS-SDK-V6-beta-integration-guide-for-developers#integration-34-support-apptrackingtransparency-att
//    if (@available(iOS 14, *)) {
//        [ATTrackingManager requestTrackingAuthorizationWithCompletionHandler:^(ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatus status) {
//            //....
//        }];
//    }
}


#pragma mark - UISceneSession lifecycle


- (UISceneConfiguration *)application:(UIApplication *)application configurationForConnectingSceneSession:(UISceneSession *)connectingSceneSession options:(UISceneConnectionOptions *)options {
    // Called when a new scene session is being created.
    // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
    return [[UISceneConfiguration alloc] initWithName:@"Default Configuration" sessionRole:connectingSceneSession.role];
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didDiscardSceneSessions:(NSSet<UISceneSession *> *)sceneSessions {
    // Called when the user discards a scene session.
    // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
    // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
}


-(void)onConversionDataFail:(NSError *) error {
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}

-(void)onConversionDataSuccess:(NSDictionary*) installData {
    id status = [installData objectForKey:@"af_status"];
    if([status isEqualToString:@"Non-organic"]) {
        id sourceID = [installData objectForKey:@"media_source"];
        id campaign = [installData objectForKey:@"campaign"];
        NSLog(@"This is a none organic install. Media source: %@  Campaign: %@",sourceID,campaign);
    } else if([status isEqualToString:@"Organic"]) {
        NSLog(@"This is an organic install.");
    }
}

- (void) onAppOpenAttribution:(NSDictionary*) attributionData {
    NSLog(@"%@",attributionData);
}

- (void) onAppOpenAttributionFailure:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}

@end
```

Comment: Do you want to have some extension for `AppDelegate` and `AppDelegateSEG`? Or you just want to have both implementations of `AppDelegate` and `AppDelegateSEG` in some other class?

Comment: I want both implementation of `AppDelegateSEG` & `FlutterAppDelegate` into `AppDelegate`. and to be honest I don't have any knowledge about extension

Comment: Looks like you don't even need this both implementations in `AppDelegate`. `AppDelegate` should and usually be implemented for each separate target without inheritance. If you need some logic (I don't sure that you do) from your `AppDelegateSEG`, you should move this necessary logic into some other place and use it directly from `AppDelegate` and `AppDelegateSEG`. Can you please show what do you want to use from `AppDelegateSEG`?

Comment: added AppDelegateSEG in question, please  check

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need only setup part, declared in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. You need to create some other class in your  `PodsSample` project where you can handle all setup. So when you need some necessary configs for AppsFlyer or SEGAnalytics, from anywhere you can just call this static (for example) method from your Pod project.

AppConfigProvider.h

```
@interface AppConfigProvider : NSObject

+ (void)setupConfig

@end
```

AppConfigProvider.m

```
#import "SEGAppsFlyerIntegrationFactory.h"
#import <AppTrackingTransparency/AppTrackingTransparency.h>

@implementation AppConfigProvider


+ (void)setupConfig {
    
    // For ApsFlyer debug logs
    [AppsFlyerLib shared].isDebug = YES;
    
//    [[AppsFlyerLib shared] waitForATTUserAutxhorizationWithTimeoutInterval:60];
    /*
     Based on your needs you can either pass a delegate to process deferred
     and direct deeplinking callbacks or disregard them.
     If you choose to use the delegate, see extension to this class below
     */
//    SEGAppsFlyerIntegrationFactory* factoryNoDelegate = [SEGAppsFlyerIntegrationFactory instance];
    SEGAppsFlyerIntegrationFactory* factoryWithDelegate = [SEGAppsFlyerIntegrationFactory createWithLaunchDelegate:self];
    
    SEGAnalyticsConfiguration *config = [SEGAnalyticsConfiguration configurationWithWriteKey:@"********"];
//    [config use:factoryNoDelegate];
    [config use:factoryWithDelegate];  // use this if you want to get conversion data in the app. Read more in the integration guide
    config.enableAdvertisingTracking = YES;       //OPTIONAL
    config.trackApplicationLifecycleEvents = YES; //OPTIONAL
    config.trackDeepLinks = YES;                  //OPTIONAL
    config.trackPushNotifications = YES;          //OPTIONAL
    [SEGAnalytics debug:YES];                     //OPTIONAL
    [SEGAnalytics setupWithConfiguration:config];
  
    NSLog(@"before delay");
    NSString *userId =  [[SEGAnalytics sharedAnalytics] getAnonymousId];
    NSLog(@"----%@", userId);
    [[SEGAnalytics sharedAnalytics] identify:(userId)];
//    [[SEGAnalytics sharedAnalytics] identify:userId];
}

@end
```

Something like this. Also you'll be need to add AppConfigProvider to public headers of your library to be visible outside

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but using this I can not achieve what I can achieve using extending AppDelegateSEG. Can you please help with something else

Comment: `UIApplicationDelegate` could be implemented in app only once. So all others won't work at all, and this case could be resolved only this way, unfortunately